# Simplifying sums of exponentials

Tags: exponential-sum, cauchy-product

I am trying to solve a tricky little problem involving sums of exponentials.

Consider the sequences $\{a_m\}$ and $\{b_m\}$. Both of these sequences are finite and $a_m>0 ~\forall m$ and $b_m>0~\forall m$.

It is always possible to find a $C$ such that
\begin{equation}
e^{-C} = \sum\limits_{m=1}^N e^{-a_m}.
\end{equation}
Simple algebraic manipulation shows that $C = -\text{log}\left(\sum\limits_{m=1}^Ne^{-a_m}\right)$.

Now I am interested in the sum 
\begin{equation}
e^{-D} = \sum\limits_{m=1}^Ne^{-a_m-b_m}.
\end{equation}

In particular, I wish to simplify the ratio between $e^{-C}$ and $e^{-D}$

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts.

If
$A
=\sum_{k=1}^n e^{-a_n}
$,
$B
=\sum_{k=1}^n e^{-b_n}
$,
and
$C
=\sum_{k=1}^n e^{-a_n-b_n}
$,
then,
depending of the ordering
of 
$(a_k)$
and
$(b_k)$,
Chebychev's sum inequality
might be of use:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_sum_inequality

Another possibility might be
to use the AM-GM inequality:
If 
$\alpha
=\sum_{k=1}^n a_n
$,

$\frac{A}{n}
\ge \left(\prod_{k=1}^n e^{-a_n} \right)^{1/n}
= \left(\exp(\sum_{k=1}^n -a_n) \right)^{1/n}
= \left(\exp(-\alpha) \right)^{1/n}
= \exp(-\alpha/n)
$,
and similarly for
$B$ and $C$.